# How can I completely remove tmux together with its .conf file?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, tmux

Is there any command that I can use to completely remove tmux and other related files such as tmux.conf, etc? Hopefully, I do not have to delete it manually.

I need to install a new copy of tmux in my arch linux so that I can get a fresh tmux.conf file.

Thanks.

Comment: According to the https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman#Removing_packages site `pacman -Rn tmux` will delete tmux and not keep configuration files around. Note that these are system configuration files, it will not alter or delete any personal configuration files. Linux programs generally work without a personal configuration file unless it is needed to specify remote user accounts.

Comment: tmux doesn't ship with a sample config file, so reinstalling will leave you no better off...

Comment: Thanks guys for the feedbacks. I have tried but it didnt work. Before I posted this, I did try `pacman -Rc tmux` but to no avail.

Comment: If tmux is not provided with a default tmux.conf file, how is it then ctrl-b is able to work right after installation? If that is the case, I do not have to remove tmux, but instead I just have to delete all contents in tmux.conf. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `pacman -Rn tmux`, will *not* remove your tmux.conf file(s).  If you know their location (should be `/etc/tmux.conf` and / or `~/.tmux.conf`) just delete them and create new one(s). If you do not know the location(s) I recommend either of two options: 1) find your `tmux.conf` using `mlocate`, then delete and replace it per your needs or 2) create a new tmux.config and pass `-f new.config.file.location` to tmux.

1) `pacman -Syu mlocate`

`updatedb` 
`locate tmux.conf` 
Then either modify `tmux.conf` or delete it and create a new one.

Or

2) create `~/.tmux.conf` then run `tmux -f ~/.tmux.conf`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback.  Could you please refer to my comments above? Maybe you could give some input.

Comment: Your last comment above is correct.  Without a config file it apparently just uses a set of defaults.  So, if you delete your _tmux.conf_ file or replace it with an empty one, you will be "starting from scratch".  FYI, you might be interested in [this link](http://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-guide-to-customizing-your-tmux-conf/).

Comment: Yup, I've seen that site before. It's just that I was wondering whether it is possible to remove all files with a single command and whether installing a new tmux comes with a new default tmux.conf file. Thanks @airhuff

Comment: And you'll probably have to reboot, too.